# TYPO3 9.2 extension builder

Tags: php, typo3, typo3-9.x

earlier in Extbase there was an initial extension builder (key: extension_builder in TER) plugin to start/configure a custom extension from scretch. Now it seems this isn't supported anymore in 9.2. TER says it goes up to version 7.6
Even if i ignore this an error will occur.

> Call to undefined method TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::extRelPath()

This bug seems to be known but never fixed in issue #81678.

Is there any possibility to use the extension builder Ext or do i need create all manually (prob common praxis now)?

Greetings Chris

Comment: you can create an extension with version typo3 8 and install that extension in the 9er version

Comment: I ceated an extension with the extension builder on v8.7. It seems there is a problem with the created extension. I can install it but it crashes frontend and backend. TYPO3 seems to catch the throwable before it is passed to the error log

Comment: check your install tool configuration and set it in debug mode! Then you see your error, alternative you can look at the error log.
Maybe in the ext_emconf.php the depends typo3 version are not supported or something

Comment: Thanks for the hint with the install tool. The domain model could not be loaded properly. Custom fields had a bad formatting. 
Creating it from scratch seems to be the best practice to avoid generated errors

Comment: Now you can report that issue on https://github.com/FriendsOfTYPO3/extension_builder like @minifranske it said ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The version on GitHub is compatible with 8 LTS

https://github.com/FriendsOfTYPO3/extension_builder

Latest version will probably work for version 9.x to. Else please create an issue there.

Answer (score 0):

extension builder 8.10.4 is not compatible with 9.5.4
Domain Modelling window stays blank

Comment: Could you give more information on how to solve the problem?